# Alternate way for sleep function

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, hp-quality-center

I have VBScript which is use to pass the test case in HP QC.

How it works:
By passing shortkeys of each button under each step.

Challenge:
Currently I am using `Sleep` in between two shortkeys.
But sometimes if the next window is not loaded and my sleep time is over 
the script will fail.

How to solve this issue?

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 5000
n = InputBox("Enter No of TC's","???")
WScript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys "^ "
WScript.Sleep 4000
For m = 1 To n-1
    objShell.SendKeys "+{DOWN}"
Next
WScript.Sleep 5000
objShell.SendKeys "^%{F9}"
WScript.Sleep 5000 
For x = 1 To n
    WScript.Sleep 8000
    objShell.SendKeys "^r"
    WScript.Sleep 8000
    objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 3000
    objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    objShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 2000
    For y = 1 To 1
        objShell.SendKeys "As Expected : "
        objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        objShell.SendKeys "^v"
        WScript.Sleep 2500 
        objShell.SendKeys "^p"
        WScript.Sleep 2500 
        objShell.SendKeys "^p"
        WScript.Sleep 2200
        objShell.SendKeys "^a"
        WScript.Sleep 2200
    Next 
    objShell.SendKeys "^q"
    WScript.Sleep 5000
Next
MsgBox "No. Of TC's executed : " & x-1
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Use AutoIt This library will allow you to better manage how to send input but also allow you to write logic that knows that a new window has been opened.

Comment: Use `Do WScript.Sleep 250 Loop Until objShell.AppActivate  " << 'YOUR TARGET WINDOW >> "= True`

Comment: how to capture the name of target window.